# Oracle dates - SQL plus - Changing the date format used in INSERT statements

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sqlplus

I am trying to run a script that has the following insert statement through sqlplus

```
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES('423234','test',NULL,'05-DEC-2012 18:30:03.000000');
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES('2343423','test',NULL,'05-DEC-2012 18:30:03.000000');
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES('234234','test',NULL,'05-DEC-2012 18:30:03.000000');
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES('234234','test',NULL,'05-DEC-2012 18:30:03.000000');
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES('2342343','test',NULL,'05-DEC-2012 18:30:04.000000');
```

When i run the script i get the following error:

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12
```

I thought this was just an issue with the NLS_DATEFORMAT parameter and all i had to do was change it for the session and it would work. The problem is i cant get the correct format.

Here is what i tried but i get a date format not recognized error

```
alter session  set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF';
```

Isn't the above pattern correct for date `'05-DEC-2012 18:30:04.000000'`

By the way the script runs fine on SQLDeveloper.

Thanks

Comment: Is the column `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`? The `FF` format element isn't recognised for `DATE`, as that doesn't support fractional seconds.

Comment: The column is defined as TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: You should **never** rely on implicit data type casting (and thus on implicit NLS settings). You should either use ANSI date literals or the `to_date()` function with a format mask to specify date values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close, but you need the [`TIMESTAMP` equivalent](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams157.htm):

```
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF';
```

It would generally be better to not rely on the NLS settings and implicit conversions, and instead do an explicit conversion:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES('2342343','test',NULL,
  TO_TIMESTAMP('05-DEC-2012 18:30:04.000000', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF');
```

It's better to explicitly list the columns too, to allow for future changes and to make it easier to check you have the values in the right order.